# Is this an appropriate edit? Placing all technical term in code tags

Tags: discussion

https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/23738249

My post was edited to place all technical terms such as "port 31503" and "IIS" in `code tags` - that doesn't seem right to me!

Comment: Are they code? If they aren't then NO...it's not appropriate.

Comment: Is there any way to flag an edit for review, then? Not that it really matters to me but I figured it would be nice to be able to alert the person who made the edit that they don't need to keep doing that...

Comment: If you think an edit is not helpful you rollback. If that edit made you post a meta-question.

Comment: If you want to tell the user that this edit is not useful, you can do "_@thepersonwhoedited the edit was not helpful and I have rolled back to the previous revision. Basic terms should not be in code format. Thanks for the edit_" below your post

Comment: I did roll back the edit, but I can't tag the person who made it, presumably because they're not in the comment thread...

Comment: @ekolis you can tag them, the autocomplete just doesn't work, but he will get notified.

Comment: Oh, great, will do!

Comment: NO. I hate this.

Comment: there is no direct way to flag an edit. What you can do instead in cases of blatantly inappropriate edit suggestions is flag the edited post, provide link to the edit review in flag message and ask moderator to consider [meta-tag:review-suspension] for reviewers who approved it

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Certainly not!

Code formatting is for code, not for technical terms.

As the post owner, you can decline edits after they got accepted through review. Please do, so the editor gets the feedback that edits like this aren't acceptable. It's very unfortunate it got through suggested edit review in the first place.

Comment: Lately there have just been some... less knowledgeable users who have been burning through the suggested edits queue approving everything.

Answer (score 9):

No. There are times when it's advantageous to have monospace for certain technical terms (clearly differentiating `l` from l, for example), but encapsulating any technical term in code blocks usually just makes the post *harder* to read.

Some folks like to `mix()` code and `! code` in sentences, and if that's how they wrote them, I typically won't go through the trouble of changing it, but I won't go adding short blocks around things just for the sake of it. Edits should make things better in some way. Harder to read isn't ..... better.